# Select specific data based on select option

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I want to select a customer name in a select dropdown list and gets its orders numbers where order status=0

On this order it contain a list of vehicles example `T1,T2,T3.....`

So after getting the order number then I get his list of vehicles.

Am expect to have three select options

I have related tables

Customer

```
Id
Name
```

Customer order

```
CustomerId
Vehiclenumber
Status
```

Finally i want to archive the vehiclenumber after select customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you can do is

```php
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}

class Order extends Model
{
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }
}
```

In the controller method which returns the view to select Customer name

```php
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        return view('some.view', ['customers' => Customer::get(['id', 'name']);
    }
}
```

Use the `$customers` to populate select options in the view. Once user clicks/selects a user, send request to the backend/server via ajax if you are using a javascript framework or plain POST request in case you are not using javascript framework for frontend. Remember to pass the `id` of the user selected by the visitor(user).

Then tackle the request in controller

```php
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function unfulfilledOrders(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);        
        $orders = $customer->orders()->where('status', 0)->get();

        return view('orders.show', ['orders' => $orders, 'customer' => $customer]);
    }
}
```

Then use the `$customer` and `$orders` variables to populate the view.

Comment: So in the foreach loop select option of customer i put $customer and select option of order i will put $orders ? An this variable $order will return order number or details of that orders?

Comment: The data returned from the `unfulfilledOrders` contains `$customer` which will have the details of the Customer previously selected by the logged in user and `$orders` will contain the Order records for that Customer where `status = 0`. Depending on the design and requirement of you frontend you can populate a select list for Orders or display them in a table with maybe Customer name as heading before the table. You can `dd($customer, $orders)` from within the controller before `return view(...)` to see what data will be available in the view

Comment: Ok,let working on design the frontend sir, soon finish it